# How to group 2 different sequences in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I group two different (first `typeof years == IEnumerable<string>` and second `typeof occurs = IEnumerable<int>`) sequences into 1 sequence by the next key: if number in `occurs` are same, then order by `years`, else order by `occurs` using only `LINQ`?

I've got these sequences in the following way:

```
var years  = some_strings.Select(x => x.Split(' ')[1]);
var occurs = years.Select(x => years.Count(e => e == x));
```

So variable `years` contains only strings with years and `occurs` contains count of same years in first sequence.

I cannot understand these techniques in `LINQ`.

Will I do something like this?

```
occurs.GroupBy(x => x ???
```

Where should I use the second sequence? 
Maybe I can got these sequences in 1 query and then process it?

**UPD**

I modified my 2 queries in 1 by using anonymous class(?):

```
    some_strings.Select(x => x.Split(' ')[1]).
    GroupBy(x => x).
    Select(x => new {num = x.Key, count = x.Count() })
```

So, there are years and occurs both in it.

I'm trying to get next string:

```
1 1990
1 1991
1 1992
2 1967
2 1968
5 2010
...
```

Now, having query with needed values, how can I sort it like foregoing clause?

Comment: Not really sure what are you trying to achieve since there is no code but the mentioned statement can be combined like 'var foo = some_strings.Split(' ')[1].Select(x => x......' based upon the return type you'll need to do casting, you can also you .Cast<> to cast the final output.

Comment: So the query in your edit does what you want?  In that case, you should post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.  If it doesn't, you need to explain what problems you have with it.

Comment: @Servy I updated my question, I hope it's a little bit clearer now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close. This should give you a list of strings similar to your latest update:

```
var occurences
    = years.GroupBy(x => x)
           .Select(x => new { Year = int.Parse(x.Key), Count = x.Count() })
           .OrderBy(x => x.Count)
           .ThenBy(x => x.Year)
           .Select(x => string.Concat(x.Count, " ", x.Year))
           .ToList();
```

Using the anonymous type you created, you can:

- order by count
- then by year
- and finally create a list of strings using `string.Concat`

*(Note that* `int.Parse` *will throw an exception if any of your strings in `years` are not actually numbers)*

Comment: Great! Works perfectly. That's exactly what I need :)